# Template rendering using underscore.js not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am using both `Backbone.js` and `Underscore.js`
Its working fine in all other browsers including IE9 but
I am Getting this error in **IE8**

```
SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier 
underscore.js, line 1156 character 7
```

Below is my code where I am getting the error

**Template**

```
<script type="text/template" id="maps-template">
    <% _.each(data, function(d) { %>
        <map id="<%= d.for %>" name="<%= d.for %>">
            <% _.each(d.area, function(d) { %>
                <area shape="<%= d.shape %>" alt="<%= d.alt %>" title="<%= d.title %>" coords="<%= d.coords %>" href="<%= d.href %>" target="_blank" />
            <% });  %>
        </map>
    <% });  %>
</script>
```

template rendering

```
pc.ui.Maps = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        var template = _.template($("#maps-template").html(), {data: pc.products.maps});
        $('body').append(template);
        return this;
    }
});

var view = new pc.ui.Maps();
```

where `pc.products.maps` is an array of objects like given below

```
pc.products.maps = [
    {
        for: "dept_a",
        area: [
            {
                coords: '426,136,618,173',
                shape: 'rect',
                href: 'example.com',
                title: '',
                alt: ''
            },
            {
                coords: '427,156,718,173',
                shape: 'rect',
                href: 'example.com',
                title: '',
                alt: ''
            },
            {
                coords: '428,186,818,173',
                shape: 'rect',
                href: 'example.com',
                title: '',
                alt: ''
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        for: 'dept_b',
        area: [
        .....
        ]
    }
];
```

Plz help me to know where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just guessing, maybe `for` is a reserved word? Try to put it in double quotes in your objects array, like `"for" : 'dept_b'` or just change that property name.

Comment: ["By default, **template** places the values from your data in the local scope via the with statement"](http://underscorejs.org/#template) so the compiled version of the template will end up trying to find a variable called `for` when within the [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with). Renaming the `for` property or using the `variable` option to to `_.template` might be necessary.